# jquery chosen plugin not working on remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I am using the jquery plugin, chosen, in a web application.  The plugin works fine with the application when I run it on my local machine.  I put the application on a remote web server and the application is not using the chosen plugin.  The chosen .js files and .css files are in the Scripts and Style folders respectively.
The paths to these files are as follows:

```
 <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<link href="~/Styles/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/> 
<script src = "/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>   
<script src = "/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

The root folder is 'Paging' and the 'Scripts folder would be /Paging/Scripts.
The styling on the web site is all there.

Do I have to register the chosen plugin on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get a 404 error in your console?

Comment: No. The web site is correctly displayed but the dropdowns are not of the 'chosen' type.  They appear as .net dropdowns and the javascript functions are not triggered when they are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able correct the problem by changing the src path the Scripts folder by adding a '.' to the path.

```
<script src = "./Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>   
<script src = "./Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "./Scripts/chosen.jquery.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope this helps someone.